# How to initialize array inside json in a NSObject class in Swift 4?

Tags: json, swift4, nsobject, swifty-json

I have a API response in JSON format like this :

```
{
"item": [
        {
            "item_id": 484,
            "user_id": 123,
            "lucky_number": -1,
            "liked_user": [
                {
                    "user_id": 2
                },
                {
                    "user_id": 1
                }
            ],
            "modified_time": "0000-09-19 10:24:02"
        }

    ]
}
```

I know how to parse the result for `item_id`,`user_id` and others in the result above.But how to get the result for `liked_user` in the response above,which is an array?

Now my NSObject class look like this:

```
class Item : NSObject {
    var itemtId :Int
    var userId : Int
    var luckyNumber : Int
    var itemCreatedAt : String

    init?(dict: [String :JSON]) {
        self.itemId = dict["item_id"]?.int ?? 0
        self.userId = dict["user_id"]?.int ?? 0
        self.luckyNumber = dict["lucky_number"]?.int ?? 0
        self.itemCreatedAt = dict["modified_time"]?.string ?? ""
    }

}
```

And then after I make a API call,I parse the response to this class like this :

```
var items = [Item]()

My ApiCall success ....  {

    let json = JSON(result) // this is SwiftyJson
    guard let itemArr = json["item"].array else{
        return
    }

    for item in itemArr {
        if let item = item.dictionary,let feed = Item.init(dict: item){
            self.items.append(feed)
    }

}
```

So my question is,in this scenario,how can I parse the data in `liked_user` and store it in my `Item` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your given code a solution is to create an array `likedUserIDs` in the class

```
class Item : NSObject {
    var itemtId :Int
    var userId : Int
    var luckyNumber : Int
    var itemCreatedAt : String
    var likedUserIDs = [Int]()

    init?(dict: [String :JSON]) {
        self.itemId = dict["item_id"]?.int ?? 0
        self.userId = dict["user_id"]?.int ?? 0
        self.luckyNumber = dict["lucky_number"]?.int ?? 0
        self.itemCreatedAt = dict["modified_time"]?.string ?? ""
        if let likedUsers = dict["liked_user"]?.array {
           for likedUser in likedUsers {
               likedUserIDs.append(likedUser["user_id"].intValue)
           }
        }
    }
}
```

---

However in Swift 4 I recommend the `(De)Codable` protocol und use structs to parse the JSON.

`SwiftyJSON` is not needed (anymore).

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let item : [Item]
}

struct Item : Decodable {
    let itemId :Int
    let userId : Int
    let luckyNumber : Int
    let itemCreatedAt : String
    let likedUsers : [LikedUser]

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case itemId = "item_id"
        case userId = "user_id"
        case luckyNumber = "lucky_number"
        case itemCreatedAt = "modified_time"
        case likedUsers = "liked_user"
    }

    struct LikedUser : Decodable {
        let userID : Int
        private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case userID = "user_id" }
    }
}
```

And decode it passing the raw JSON as `Data` object

```
do {
    let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print("error: ", error)
}
```

Comment: Have you intentionally left out the implementation for `init(from:)`? To my understanding, as soon as you provide custom keys for the `CodingKey` you should/must implement the `init(from:)` by yourself. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The coding keys are for changing *snake_cased* keys to *camelCase*. `init(from:` is not needed

Answer (score 0):

I think the result for `liked_user` is a array that contains two `Json` object.
Below code block will be helpful to you.

```
let liked_users = json["liked_user"].array
for liked_user in liked_users {
    let user_id = liked_user["user_id"].int
}
```

You can save the user_id to a array in your `Item` class.

```
class Item : NSObject {
    var itemId :Int
    var userId : Int
    var luckyNumber : Int
    var itemCreatedAt : String
    var useridArray: [Int] = []

    init?(dict: [String :JSON]) {
        self.itemId = dict["item_id"]?.int ?? 0
        self.userId = dict["user_id"]?.int ?? 0
        self.luckyNumber = dict["lucky_number"]?.int ?? 0
        self.itemCreatedAt = dict["modified_time"]?.string ?? ""
        if let liked_users = dict["liked_user"]?.array { 
            for liked_user in liked_users {
                if let userid = liked_user["user_id"]?.int {
                    useridArray.append(userid)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can u show me how to store the arrayof my userIdArray in my Item class? cause this is the reason why I asked this question

Comment: The class does not compile.

Comment: @ken I hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: No, it's a `class has not initialized properties` error but after adding the initialization line the error goes away. However you should initialize the array in the declaration line.

Comment: Please, learn to use `map` and `flatMap`. `userIdArray = dict["liked_user"]?.arrayValue.flatMap { $0["user_id"]?.int }`

Answer (score 0):

Create a likedUsersArray var in your Item object and then parse the array of dictionaries in this way:

```
 class Item : NSObject {
    var itemtId :Int
    var userId : Int
    var luckyNumber : Int
    var itemCreatedAt : String
    var likedUsersArray: [Int] = []

    init?(dict: [String :JSON]) {
        self.itemId = dict["item_id"]?.int ?? 0
        self.userId = dict["user_id"]?.int ?? 0
        self.luckyNumber = dict["lucky_number"]?.int ?? 0
        self.itemCreatedAt = dict["modified_time"]?.string ?? ""
        for likedUserDict in dict["liked_user"]?.array {
            if let dict = likedUserDict?.dictionary, let likedUserId = dict["user_id"].int {                    
                self.likedUsersArray.append(likedUserId)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `cannot subsript of value of a type '[JSON]' with index of type 'String'.`Bro I getting this error

Comment: `Cast from '[JSON]?' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always fails` and also `Value of tuple type '(key: String, value: Any)' has no member 'subscript'` I got this now

Comment: Try casting likedUserDict to SwiftyJson dictionary, I have edited my answer again.

Comment: `Value of optional type '[JSON]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?` have a lot of this kind of warning..when I fix it,the app cant compile

Comment: still the same..Later I try again